# Installing Jenkins on a webserver

Tags: jenkins, webserver, continuous-integration, installation

I've searched the whole internet for this. I have a website that is run by a hosting company. All the tutorials to install Jenkins assume I'm running my own Linux machine and can perform various commands.

Is there a way I can install Jenkins on this website using only FTP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe. If your hosting company provides Tomcat (or another servlet container/J2EE server like JBoss) then you can install Jenkins as a webapp inside of Tomcat. Typically it just involves placing the jenkins.war file in $TOMCAT_BASE/webapps.

If your hosting company does not provide Tomcat and doesn't allow you to run Java yourself from a shell then AFAIK you can't run Jenkins.